How can I acquire a token in .NET framework for an OAuth connection?
I have several web services making http requests to some API. They are using OAuth 2.0.
The web services (.NET 6) use Microsoft.Identity.Client to get the access token, like this:
var clientId = "some-id";
var clientSecret = "some-secret";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-domain";
var scope = "api://my-resource/.default";

string[] scopes = new string[] { scope };

IConfidentialClientApplication app;
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
   .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
   .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
   .Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

var token = result.AccessToken

That token is valid and it lets my web service access the API, using HttpClient. It works perfectly.
Now I have a problem: there's a legacy .NET framework application that can't be updated to .NET Core, and it needs to also access the API, using Microsoft libraries only.
I tried using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory and this code:
var clientId = "some-id";
var clientSecret = "some-secret";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-domain";
var scope = "api://my-resource/.default";

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scope, clientCredential);

var token = result.AccessToken;

However, I get an exception:

AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://my-resource/.default was not found in the tenant named MY-TENANT.

I am completely out of ideas as to how to obtain the token in .NET 4.8 for an OAuth connection.
Any insights regarding this will be highly appreciated.

looking at one of our .Net Framework apps: authority is "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".  The scope value comes from the App registration of the API being called - it is the Application ID URI.  It looks like api:///.   That value also shows up in the Scopes on 'Expose an API' tab of the API App registration. HTH

Thanks for your comment. It seems to be something related to the way I created the "scope" value. If I remove the api:// part of it, it doesn't fail and creates a token, however that token is useless as it doesn't authorize the client to connect to the resource. In the end we had to upgrade .Net Framework from 4.5 to 4.6.1 and use Microsoft.Identity.Client.
